# Is there any way to check if DropDownList is bound to my data source?

Tags: asp.net

I have ASP.NET DropDownList control, and I need to check if the control is bound to my data source.

How can I check if ASP.NET DropDownList control is bound to my data source?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the controls `DataSource` and `DataSourceID` property. That will let you know. If it's bound to any declarative data source then it will have it's `DataSourceID` property set else the `DataSource` property of the control will be set.

For Example, try the below code sample

```
        DataTable dt = new DataTable("Test");
        this.GridView1.DataSource = dt;
        Response.Write(this.GridView1.DataSource.ToString());
```

Will result in `Test`